# PubNub publish message between two Private Channels

Tags: pubnub

I'm using Php and MySQL.

I have just signup for pubnub push API and successfully made my first push notification using the PHP Push API provided by Pubnub. I'm new into this Realtime technology so I have come up with some questions which I find confusing to understand myself. I have googled many times and searched all over stackoverflow. I didn't get any relevant suggestions or questions elsewhere, so I'm writing down my question here seeking your advice and expertise help.

Pubnub says it's not a good thing to create more than two channels per client. So, in my application, I have a requirement to create more than two channels to listen to notifications happening everywhere on my website but I will go with two channels for every logged in users as Pubnub suggested.

1. Logged in users listens to Channel1-Public
2. Logged in users listens to private UsersOwnDynamic-Channel to receive notifications related and only meant for him.

FYI: [This link in PubNub says about creating LongChannel names to avoid Channel Snooping](https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21115547-how-do-i-allow-only-certain-users-to-subscribe-to-certain-channels)

My questions are given below: 
A. Do I always have to create a new private Dynamic channel name everytime I logged into the website. If so, how would other users know how to send a notification to my private Channel.Or, do I just need to have only one static channel name stored in database table, so that other authenticated users will query the table and get my private channel name to sent me notifications. If this is the case, don't you think if a hacker get hold of some private channel name of certain users, they will be able to listen to that channel?

B.I'm using PHP and MySQL, so I still cannot think out a way or come up with a solution to send message to private channels of another user. 
Lets take an example for a simple friend request system. 
- UserA sends a friend request to UserB. 
- UserB is listening to his own dynamic private channel name called DynamicPrivateChannelB 
(how will UserA find the channel name for UserB which is private? Im thinking the only way for this is that the private channel of UserB should be stored in a database table for every loggedin users to query. Am I thinking the right way ? )

```
<?php 

    //first way. How can i possibly achieve this.
    $sqlquery = "sent friend request from userA to userB"; 
    require('Pubnub.php'); 
    $pubnub = new Pubnub( 'pubkey', 'subkey' );
    $pubnub->publish( array(
        'channel' => 'how do i find the private channel name for userB to sent this notification?', 
                    'message' => array('friend_request' => 'A friend request') ) 
                    );

  //2nd way ? Is this the right way ?
    $sqlquery = "sent friend request from userA to userB"; 
    $privatechannelofuserB = "get the channel name of userB from the db table";
    require('Pubnub.php'); 
    $pubnub = new Pubnub( 'pubkey', 'subkey' );
    $pubnub->publish( array(
        'channel' => '$privatechannelofuserB', 
                    'message' => array('friend_request' => 'A friend request') ) 
                    );
?>
```

C. If we are always generating dynamic private channel names, storing in database table, updating whenever new dynamic channel names are generated. I think it will cause a problem because some message won't get delivered as new dynamic private channel names replaces old ones.

D. So, I have many notifications to sent to a single channel like New Friends request, New Private message replies, New gifts requests and many others like that. How do I sent all these data to a channel and how to find out and parse the incoming new notifications data. I know JSON is the format to send but im not sure about the format of sending.

According to [this link](https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21115547-how-do-i-allow-only-certain-users-to-subscribe-to-certain-channels), a single Pubnub channel can contain only up to 100 messages. Does it mean that if 200 messages comes at once to a single channel the first 100 gets delivered and the remaining is on queue ? How about if 10,000 messages comes at once to a single channel ? Do all the remaining messages stays in queue ? if so, how does it gets delivered to the subscriber in realtime ?

Let me give another simple scenario that I'm trying to achieve.

> - **UserA** is authenticated and logged in to the website.
> - **UserA** generates his own Dynamic channel name, **UserAx732dsw3efsdfsdfsdf**
> - **UserA** starts listening to his newly created channel **UserAx732dsw3efsdfsdfsdf** 
>    (Now, userA should start receiving messages from others)
>
> - **UserB** sends a private message to **userA**. 
>  (Now, only userA should get notified on his private channel about the new private
>   message, how can **userB**  or the **System** find out the channel
>   name **UserAx732dsw3efsdfsdfsdf** because, this is a private channel
>   generated dynamically by **userA** , neither the **System** or
>   **userB** has accessed to it. This same thing is happening for **userB** as well, if **userB** should be notified by any other entity or by the system again, there should be a way to find out the dynamic
>   channel name of **userB** . 
>   
>   Another issue is this scenario is that, if a user is dynamically generating channel name everytime he/she logged in to the website. What will happen to all the messages that was sent to the dynamic channel ? Do pubnub saves all the created channel names on their server? Is there any way that a system or a user can find out whether a channel name is still being own and atleast one user is listening to the channel ?.  
>  
>   I'm curious to know this because of the following concepts that I have:
>
> - **UserA** creates **dynamicChannelA** when he/she logged in to the website at **1AM**.
> - UserA starts getting lots of notification pushout to his dynamic channel **dynamicChannelA**
> - Now, **UserA** logs out from the website at **1:30 AM**, what will happen to the many other users who are still pushing out notification
>     to his **dynamicChannelA** because by the next time when **UserA**
>     logs into the website, **UserA** will be listening to different
>     dynamic channel name.**UserA** won't be listening to his previous
>     channel **dynamicChannelA** .

I'm thinking to use the method of retrieving channel name of a particular user from the database table. Is there any method or way to prevent unauthorised subscription of the channel? Because anybody can subscribe to the channel name if they have the subscribe key and channel name no matter how long the channel name is. I'm just curious because all subscription is happening in the client side and the subscription key and channel names are visible.

Comment: Hi RT Roger.  Thank you for the questions!  This is a really detailed list.  We will provide feedback this week.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know, i'll wait for the feedback.

Comment: Check this answer if that is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666799/real-time-chat-in-php-redis-pub-sub-websockets-nodejs/42860273#42860273

Comment: @RTRoger I am having the same doubts

Answer (score 30):

There's no one single way of tackling the issues that you've run into.  Our customers have used a wide variety of design patterns to deal with them.  I myself have run into this type of thing building PubNub apps and I'll help you as much as I can.

> Pubnub says its not a good thing to create more than two channels per client. So, in my application, i have a requirement to create more than two channels to listen to notifications happening everywhere on my website but i will go with two channels for every logged in users as Pubnub suggested.
>
> Logged in users listens to Channel1-Public 
>   Logged in users listens to private UsersOwnDynamic-Channel to receive notifications related and only meant for him.

This is a good way to do it, and the way many of our massive scale customers do it.  A global channel and a private, user-only channel.

## A.

> Do i always have to create a new private Dynamic channel name everytime i logged into the website.

Not necessarily, though this is a good way.  You can use `PUBNUB.uuid()` in JavaScript on the client-side to do this.  Or, generate it server-side using PHP and render it to the client.  Maybe you could set it as a cookie so the client always has access to it.

> If so, how would other users know how to send a notification to my private Channel.

They could get the id's from the PHP server; either via the global channel or the user's own private channel, which they are listening to.

> Or, do i just need to have only one static channel name stored in database table, so that other authenticated users will query the table and get my private channel name to sent me notifications.

You could do it this way too.  You might have the global channel the users can send to be different then the global channel they are listening to.  Only the server has **that** subscribe key.  Thus, authenticated users send a message to the server that tells it "I need the appropriate user keys", then the server does a query and sends a message back on that users private channel.

> If this is the case, don't you think if a hacker get hold of some private channel name of certain users, they will be able to listen to that channel?

If you withhold the subscribe key on the global send channel, only the server can see the chatter on that channel.

## B.

> Im using PHP and mysql, so i still cannot think out a way or come up with a solution to send message to private channels of another user. 
>   Lets take an example for a simple friend request system. 
>   - UserA sends a friend request to UserB. 
>   - UserB is listening to his own dynamic private channel name called DynamicPrivateChannelB 
>   (how will UserA find the channel name for UserB which is private? Im thinking the only way for this is that the private channel of UserB should be stored in a database table for every loggedin users to query. Am i thinking the right way ? )

This is very similar to your previous question.  There's no one way to do it, but the design pattern I outlined above should work.  To recap this design pattern:

### Server side

- Listens on Global-user-send-channel for user messages.  The server is the only entity that has this subscribe key
- Can query db to get user-ids, and then send to the various ids at will
- Can also send on the Global-user-receive-channel, which all clients are listening on.  The server is the only entity that has this publish key.

### Client side

- Listens on Global-user-receive-channel.  This is how it gets mass server broadcasts. Cannot send on this channel (only has subscribe key)
- Sends server messages on Global-user-send-channel.  Cannot recieve on this channel (only has publish key)
- Listens on private user channel.  This is how user gets private messages.  It can also use this for client-to-client communication.
- Prevent abuse by appending all private messages with a private, per-user key stored on the server, and provided during the initial page-load. That way, a client knows if a message claiming to be from the server is legit.

## C.

> If we are always generating dynamic private channel names, storing in database table, updating whenever new dynamic channel names are generated. I think it will cause a problem because some message won't get delivered as new dynamic private channel names replaces old ones.

If you're careful about when you generate new channel names, this shouldn't be a problem.  Keep in mind, the client can always say on the Global-user-send-channel 'hey, I'm here!  this is my id.  keep me updated'.  I usually design my apps to have the clients automatically shout this out every 30 seconds or so.

## D.

> So, i have many notifications to sent to a single channel like New Friends request, New Private message replies, New gifts requests and many others like that. How do i sent all these data to a channel and how to find out and parse the incoming new notifications data. I know JSON is the format to send but im not sure about the format of sending.

JSON is good for sending and recieving.  The way I do it is to have a property called "name" which defines what type of message it is.   For example:

```
{
    "id"   : "blah_blah_unique_id",    // sender_client_id 
    "name" : "friend_request",         // type of message
    "data" : {                         // the data itself
               "requested_friend_id" : "blah_blah_some_other_unique_id" 
             }
}
```

You can actually use whatever format you want, but we'll wrap it in JSON (usually that means just wrapped in quotes) when it gets pushed through PubNub.

Hope this helps!

### New Questions

> According to [this link](https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21115547-how-do-i-allow-only-certain-users-to-subscribe-to-certain-channels), a single Pubnub channel can contain only upto 100 messages. Does it mean that if 200 messages comes at once to a single channel the first 100 gets delivered and the remaining is on queue ? How about if 10,000 messages comes at once to a single channel ? Do all the remaining messages stays in queue ? if so, how does it gets delivered to the subscriber in realtime ?

The 100 message limit is in regards to PubNub.history.  If someone is subscribed and 200 messages come in, they will receive all 200 messages.

> (Now, only userA should get notified on his private channel about the new private message, how can userB or the System find out the channel name UserAx732dsw3efsdfsdfsdf because, this is a private channel generated dynamically by userA , neither the System or userB has accessed to it. This same thing is happening for userB as well, if userB should be notified by any other entity or by the system again, there should be a way to find out the dynamic channel name of userB .

There's no one-size-fits-all solution to this question, but what I'd do is have the server generate that unique id on page load and render it to the client on your initial HTTP request.

> Another issue is this scenario is that, if a user is dynamically generating channel name everytime he/she logged in to the website. What will happen to all the messages that was sent to the dynamic channel ? Do pubnub saves all the created channel names on their server?

You don't have to dynamically generate every time.  You could.... but you also set a cookie with that unique id, or pull it from the database and render it to the client on page load (that's what I'd do).   We don't save channel names.

> Is there any way that a system or a user can find out whether a channel name is still being own and atleast one user is listening to the channel ?.

Not out of the box, but you could implement this easily.  Just have your server send out a ping and set up your clients to always respond to pings if they're listening.

> Now, UserA logs out from the website at 1:30 AM, what will happen to the many other users who are still pushing out notification to his dynamicChannelA because by the next time when UserA logs into the website, UserA will be listening to different dynamic channel name.UserA won't be listening to his previous channel dynamicChannelA .

The way you can prevent this is periodic (every 30 seconds?) pings from the server, who can keep track if users are still there.  In the coming months we'll be launching a presence API to do this automatically, btw.

> Im thinking to use the method of retrieving channel name of a particular user from the database table. Is there any method or way to prevent unauthorised subscription of the channel? Because anybody can subscribe to the channel name if they have the subscribe key and channel name no matter how long the channel name is. Im just curious because all subscription is happening in the client side and the subscription key and channel names are visible

The main way is strategically witholding publish/subscribe keys.  You're right that anyone with the proper details can listen in - this is a big problem of client-only systems.  For the time being, you'll have to come up with creative ways to get around it.

Comment: Hello @Phil Deschaine thank you so much for your valuable insights on the design pattern describe above.So, do you meant that my Server side code can subscribe to Channels and respond to incoming message, process and publish message to whoever it is meant for? Do i have to run a special PHP script that subscribes to Global-user-send-channel in the background, is this the right way? Do you think it will eat lots of server memory and resources ?Also could you please check my questions above, i have added more questions after reading your answers. Thanks alot for your response.