# pubnub channel audit not showing grants

Tags: audit, sql-grant, pubnub, pam

Recently a production app of mine began throwing exceptions due to some weird behavior with the grant/audit functions.  To summarize, I can grant permissions to a channel/key combo and get a success response but when I audit the channel immediately afterwards it shows an empty channels result set.  To rule out a bug in the application I verified this behavior in the pubnub developer console.

**Grant Input/Output**

[grant input screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHFrz.png)

```
RESPONSE:
{
  "auths": {
    "102cd0f27f216cc3ce7733e7a56ce1ae9e35407c": {
      "r": 1,
      "w": 0
    }
  },
  "subscribe_key": "sub-c-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ttl": 0,
  "channel": "32f563fcc122d2b0db5f133b0967bcd8",
  "level": "user"
}
```

**Audit Input/Output**

[audit input screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aCYC.png)

```
RESPONSE:
{
  "channels": {

  },
  "subscribe_key": "sub-c-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "level": "channel"
}
```

I would expect to see the permissions that were just granted in the audit.  Am I missing something silly?

Thanks.

Comment: TTL 0 is currently unavailable.  Try granting with a very high TTL.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Grant/Revoke and Audit

This is unintended behavior and TTL 0 should work as you expect for a **Forever Grant**.  We are working on the issue and will have it resolved shortly for you.  Right now any grants less than 5 TTL are not saved.  The instant solution for you right now is to grant above TTL of 5.

PubNub offers Access Control Management with Data Channels offering grant/revoke admin privileges to control permissions for your real time streams at the user/device, channel or key level.  Access Control starts with Auth tokens from any existing authentication system like Facebook Connect, Twitter, Google, LDAP, or homegrown solutions.

PAM is a Serverless, easy to use, key based security solution for all of your apps
allowing you to manage users and intervene in user actions when needed on a per subscriber basis.  By default PubNub does not require ACL or security restrictions.  With PubNub Access Manager you can provide Authorization and access control to channels for your users.

[image: PubNub Access Manager]

Comment: Some of PubNub's own responses to user questions suggest using a TTL of 0 for an indefinite auth.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21176844/2925455 .  Is there any explanation or reason for the sudden change?

Comment: Matt Z you are correct!  This is an unintended behavior and TTL 0 should work as you expect for a **Forever Grant**.  We are working on the issue and will have it resolved shortly.

Comment: Oops, I did mean Forever Grant and not "indefinite".  Thanks for the update.